# Is there a way to export SAS number using commas instead of dots?

Tags: sas

The question is pretty straightforward.

When I do calculations on SAS and export them to an Excel spreadsheet, the numbers are exported using a dot as a decimal delimiter. Can I use a comma as a decimal delimiter when exporting on SAS software?

For example, I have this number: 32.53 but I want it exported to Excel as 32,53.

Comment: Yes, there's a french style format for numbers that uses commas instead of decimals. If you apply that format does it get exported as desired? NUMX or COMMAX formats. https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/leforinforref/64790/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n12v1pgo24u3fln1x1982m5xowuj.htm

Answer (score 1):

When I tested this, the decimal separator (`.` in the US, `,` in some European countries) was controlled entirely by the NLS setting in Windows.

To test this, I exported a list of numbers, saw they looked like `0.1`, went into Windows control panel, Region and Language, changed Decimal Symbol (on Additional Settings on the first tab) to `,`, re-opened Excel and they now looked like `0,1` in the exported file.

Be careful using the `NUMXw.d` format as suggested elsewhere; it's very easy to get thousands and decimal switched in Excel.  See for example this:

```
data test;
  do x = 1 to 2 by 0.1;
    y=x;
    output;
  end;
  format y numx8.3;
run;

ods excel file="c:\temp\test_ods.xlsx";
  proc print data=test;
  run;
ods excel close;
```

Excel prints the numbers as you'd want in the `y` column - but they're actually *thousands*.  Oops!

`ODS Excel` does not have an option to set the decimal separator.  `ODS Tagsets.ExcelXP` claims to, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could use several notations (FLOAT4, REAL+4, float, E, FLOAT BIN(21)) but not the delimiter itself. Contrary it can be changed in Excel.

Nonetheless, try to look at [NUMXw.d](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000194648.htm)